# React js bundle not loading in Android App

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

while loading my react js bundle in android app im getting blank page ,  getting this error : Uncaught ReferenceError :
'globalThis is not defined                                                          '

Any possible solutions or what is wrong in the code,Does the issue is from js or android
any solutions welcome ,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.